# What's the easiest way to deploy a a Multiservices Spring/Python project on the AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, web-deployment

I have created a Multiservices Spring/Python project. What's the easiest way to deploy it on the AWS cloud with 4 machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple Services to achieve the same :

1. ElasticBeanstalk: If you have you code then you upload it on ElasticBeanstalk and any newer version just upload it on the Beanstalk and choose the deployment method it will automatically be deployed on the machine. You can choose the whatever number of instances you want to spin along with LoadBalancer and more.

Documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html)

2. CodePipeline: Have your code pushed into CodeCommit or Github or S3 and let it use CodeCommit, CodeBuild and CodeDeploy to deploy it on your EC2 server.

Documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cd-pipeline.html)

3. CloudFormation: This service you can use to spin up your services just through code. It is called Infrastructure as Code. Write code and spin up the instances.

Documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html)